# Is there a way to modify the OS X login screen accessibility preferences from the Terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, accessibility, plist

I do school technology support, mostly on a bunch of Macs running OS X 10.11.6. We have a ne'er-do-well student who keeps running around to the various computers and modifying the login screen accessibility settings (done by pressing Command+Option+F5 and turning on several checkboxes), which makes the login screen difficult for people to use. I'm constantly playing catch-up to undo these settings, because most people at the school don't know how to bring up the settings window. Short of educating every user how to reset the preferences by themselves, is there a way to programmatically set this using bash, from the Terminal/ARD?

Using `find / -mmin -2` from the Terminal right after modifying the accessibility settings on the login window, I found several plist files that seem to reference the universal access feature, some of which respond when the settings are changed:

```
/private/var/root/Library/Containers/com.apple.ctkd/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
/private/var/db/securityagent/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
```

I experimented a bit already, by trying the following:

1. Used ARD to directly overwrite what appears to be the "primary" plist (stands by itself; not referenced by another process in its path) with data from a "known good" one:

   ```
   printf '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>closeViewHotkeysEnabled</key>
   <false/>
   <key>closeViewScrollWheelToggle</key>
   <false/>
   <key>closeViewZoomFactor</key>
   <real>1</real>
   <key>login</key>
   <false/>
   <key>mouseDriver</key>
   <false/>
   <key>slowKey</key>
   <false/>
   <key>slowKeyDelay</key>
   <integer>250</integer>
   <key>stickyKey</key>
   <false/>
   <key>useStickyKeysShortcutKeys</key>
   <false/>
   <key>voiceOverOnOffKey</key>
   <false/>
   <key>whiteOnBlack</key>
   <false/>
   </dict>
   </plist>' > /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
   ```
2. Used "defaults write" to modify individual settings:

   ```
   defaults write /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist stickyKey -bool False
   ```

In each of these cases, when I use `plutil -p /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist` to view the resulting plist, the settings have been changed successfully. However, the next time `loginwindow` is invoked, on logout, or by killing the process manually, the settings and associated plists revert to their previous settings. It's like there's some sort of deeper master record that they pull from; that the generated plists are just results of a different parent process.

Does anybody have any expertise in this area? Much appreciated, if you do.

Comment: A handy article, but not quite what I'm aiming for. I have no problems with the accessibility permissions (allowing apps in user-space to manipulate the computer using accessibility interfaces), but rather, setting the out-of-user-space parameters for the login screen itself, such as VoiceOver, color inversion, etc.

Edit: This was originally in reply to a link to information about editing the TCC.db file, which controls accessibility permissions per-app.

Comment: After you change/update/save the `.plist` kill any instances of the `cfprefsd` processes on the machine, then save it once more — the change might then hold.

Comment: That worked splendidly! I was able to rewrite the accessibility preferences on multiple computers I had available, after deliberately "breaking" them. So, if I'm inferring this correctly, cfprefsd is the process the actual plists are "loaded into", and when they're rewritten and mismatch its own internal information, it writes back to them to correct the fault? Either way, thanks a million.

Comment: The preferences are more or less cached and the cfprefsd is the daemon that keeps them loaded. Killing the process sends the cached preferences into oblivion :)